# how to convert string to byte() vb.net?

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net, compiler-errors, byte

error msg i got : 
system.byte{}

code :

Module Module1

```
Sub Main()

    Dim qassam As String = "mylove"
    Dim lena As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(qassam)

    Console.WriteLine(lena)


    Console.ReadLine()


End Sub
```

End Module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have successfully encoded the string into a `byte()`. But you can't output this byte-array with `Console.WriteLine` because then only the type-name is written.

You could use:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", lena))
```

---

On .NET 2.0 you could use this approach:

```
Dim lenaStrings = Array.ConvertAll(lena, Function(b) b.ToString())
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", lenaStrings))
```

Comment: i got this error :
Error 1 Value of type '1-dimensional array of Byte' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of String' because 'Byte' is not derived from 'String'. c:\users\evilcode1\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Module1.vb 11 44 ConsoleApplication2

Comment: @QassamMahmoud: What .NET version are you using? You could use following with .NET3.5(although ugly):  `Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",lena.Select(Function(b)b.ToString()).ToArray()))`

Comment: version 2 , when i used 4 it's working but i dont need it on 4 i need it to work on version 2 is there anyway to do that ?

Comment: @QassamMahmoud: try my new approach. You need a `String()` for the old String.Join. Array.ConvertAll is the cheapest way to create one from the Byte()